# Index creation in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

When I use groupby on a pandas dataframe, an index is automatically created by the column I used for grouping. If I want to use that column later, I can do something like:

```
df['index1'] = df.index
```

Is there a way, I can use groupby and not create the index? Specifying  as_index=False does not work.

Comment: Can you show the full groupby call you are doing? (ideally with a small reproducible example)

Answer (score 2):

Specify `as_index=False` in the groupby call. See the [groupby docstring](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

(although it will depend on the exact operation you do on the groupby object afterwards if this will have effect or not).

Comment: modified question to reflect that

Comment: You have to show the full code you are trying to be able to say more.